# How to configure Eclipselink nosql JPA implementation with mongodb nosql database?

Tags: mongodb, jakarta-ee, jpa, mongodb-java, java-ee-7

I want to use JPA to create an entity class that can be used with the persistence context to access my db2 nosql database. The problem is the `@NoSql` annotation is not being found.

As per http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/NoSQL/Configuring, I:

1. Created a web project
2. Enabled JPA via project properties-> Project Facets -> Check mark JPA v2.1
3. Under Project properties -> JPA -> Set Platform to EclipseLink 2.5x, Set JPA Implementation to Library Provided by Target Runtime
4. Setup server.xml with the datasource and the persistence.xml

I have java.persistence.org but not java.persistence.org.oracle.nosql. I'm not sure if I am suppose to download it or it should already be setup. And I also do not know how to use maven (and I would prefer not to).

Most tutorials online either only show HOW to use (and not configure) or use mysql connector and somewhere in the project config it just works. I greatly appreciate assistance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by following this blog post: https://blogs.oracle.com/NoSQL/entry/eclipselink_jpa_and_oracle_nosql.

Excerpt:

> Now at first glance it looks like EclipseLink 2.5 includes support for
>   NoSQL databases right out of the box, but in fact if you look closely
>   there is another specific NoSQL plugin download necessary. Download,
>   unzip and save this plugin in a directory e.g. /nosql-plugin . Later
>   you’ll need to get some libraries from it.

So go [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/rt/eclipselink/releases/2.5.0/eclipselink-plugins-nosql-2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b.zip&mirror_id=492) to get the jar files and import the following into your project

1. org.eclipse.persistence.nosql_2.5.0*.jar
2. org.eclipse.persistence.oracle.nosql_2.5.0*.jar
3. javax.resource_1.5.0*.jar

To import go right-click project -> properties -> java build path -> Libraries tab -> Add External Jar -> Navigate to the jar files and import

Comment: Oracle Blogs - We can't find the page you were looking for. https://blogs.oracle.com/NoSQL/entry/eclipselink_jpa_and_oracle_nosql. Have you a working blog?